# Tools for detecting packing and encryption

Tags: malware

I'm doing a cert in malware analysis and I'm looking for some up to date tools to automate detection of packing and encryption to aid the reversing process.

I've found TitanMist however it seems quite dated, are there any other tools?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Encrypted and compressed data have high entropy. Tools for visualizing the entropy of information in binary files include [binvis.io](http://binvis.io/#/) and [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk).

Comment: Thanks I’ve been looking for this since I seen it used in a book I read

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to native applications in particular then [Detect it Easy](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy) is one of the better and more widely used options.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go! 23 hours last commit :)